# How to parse multiline records in groovy?

Tags: regex, parsing, groovy

I have log file containing somewhere five * in two places. The file can be big.

```
Log record
*****
Log record
Log record
*****
Log record
```

I would like to get everything which is between five *. Right, I can read line by line but perhaps there are better solutions like parsing using Regular Expressions in Groovy?

Thank you.

Comment: How big can be the file? Might be worth trying a solution which read the file in chunks, like `File.eachLine { }`

Comment: The file can be several hundreds KB. It looks like two options. Read line by line or read whole file to String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also write a custom Reader like:

```
class DelimitedReader extends BufferedReader {
    String delimiterLine

    DelimitedReader( String delimiterLine, Reader reader ) {
        super( reader )
        this.delimiterLine = delimiterLine
        scanUntilDelimiter()
    }

    private scanUntilDelimiter() {
        String line = super.readLine()
        while( line != null && line != delimiterLine ) {
            line = super.readLine()
        }
    }

    String readLine() {
        String line = super.readLine()
        if( line == delimiterLine ) {
            line = null
        }
        line
    }
}
```

And then, you can do something like this to iterate over them

```
new File( '/tmp/test.txt' ).withReader { r ->
    new DelimitedReader( '*****', r ).eachLine { line ->
        println line
    }
}
```

This saves you having the whole file loaded in to a single (potentially huge) string

Comment: Hello Tim_yates, thank you. I was also thinking about custom reader and you provided implementation. Custom reader is solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?s)(?<=[*]{5}).+(?=[*]{5})
```

#### Demo

http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/2405001

Comment: thank you. Looks like I need to read whole file in a string object, right? The file can be several hundreds KB. Is it still worth to read it to the string object?

Comment: it can be Linux or Windows, perhaps later can be some other platforms.

Comment: Even if its hundred of KB, I think you can load the file in a String object. It would be hundreds *MB*,  a line by line approach would be better then.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches everything between the first `*****` and the next one:

```
(?<=\*{5})[\s\S]*(?=\*{5})
```